# WooCommerce Category Images flipped horizontally?

Tags: wordpress, image, woocommerce

All the images on my category pages in Wordpress WooCommerce are flipped horizontally by default. When the product image is clicked, it displays in the correct orientation on the individual product page.

Link:

https://uglydukling.ca/product-category/hello-kitty/

How do i make all images on the category page display in the correct orientation?

Comment: Please bring the relevant code to reproduce the problem into your question.  Questions on Stack Overflow are for _future visitors_ as much as for you, so once your link is [broken|fixed|closed|changed], this question has zero value to a future visitor.

Comment: Additionally - none of the pictures are flipped when I view the site.

Comment: Not exactally sure what code to add to this question. If you look carefully at the product images on the catageory page, they are all flipped (mirrored), the text in the photos are backwards.

Answer (score 0):

You have a custom CSS code inserted on your shop which is flipping the images parent wrapper div:

```
.products .product figure.product-transition-fade .img-wrap.first-image {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
z-index: 3;
transform: scaleX(-1);}
```

So **transform: scaleX(-1);** is flipping your image parent wrapper, try to remove that line and your images will be fine.

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scaleX

[image: Inspect Screenshot]

Comment: Done. Thank you!! appreciate the help.